# Option 1:1 mapping, main entity doesn't have FK in it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using entity framework 4, mvc4 and code first.

I'm struggling with creating an option 1:1 mapping, where the main entity that has the optional 1:1 mapping doesn't have the FK in it:

```
public class User
{
   [Column("user_id")]
   public int Id {get;set;}

   public virtual House House {get;set;}  // optional mapping
}

public class House
{
   [Column("house_id")]
   public int Id {get;set;}

   [Column("user_id")]
   public int UserId {get;set;}
}
```

Notice how the user table doesn't have teh houseId column.

**How can I map this correctly?**

*Note: the below method isn't what i really want to do since it forces me to add a navigational property on the House model also back to User.*

I tried this method, although I had to add a virtual property to the House model which I didn't want to do: [How do I code an optional one-to-one relationship in EF 4.1 code first with lazy loading and the same primary key on both tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434245/how-do-i-code-an-optional-one-to-one-relationship-in-ef-4-1-code-first-with-lazy)

So my configuration looks like with the above attempt:

```
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
        {
            public UserConfiguration()
            {
                this.ToTable("User", SchemaName);
                this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
                this.HasOptional(x => x.House);
            }
        }

    public class HouseConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<House>
    {
        public HouseConfiguration()
        {
            this.ToTable("House", SchemaName);
            this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            this.HasRequired(vc => vc.User).WithRequiredDependent(v => v.House);
        }
    }
```

But when I do this, saving the model I get this error:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'House' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF
```

Note:  without the above setup (mapping and configuration), the House entity saves just fine to the database and the identity is setup correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `UserId` property from `House`, remove the `this.HasRequired...` mapping from the `HouseConfiguration` constructor and use in `UserConfiguration`:

```
this.HasOptional(x => x.House).WithRequired();
```

This will define a shared primary key association (i.e. `House.Id` is primary key of `House` and the foreign key to `User` at the same time).

If you have an existing database with a separate foreign key column `user_id` in the `House` table and this column has a unique key constraint to enforce a one-to-one relation in the database you cannot map this as one-to-one relationship with Entity Framework because EF doesn't support foreign key one-to-one associations.

You would have to map this as one-to-many relationship in this case and unfortunately you can't have a single reference `House` on the principal `User`. You would have to use a collection of `House`es instead (and ensure in business logic that you never add more than one element to this collection, otherwise upon saving you would get an exception due to a violation of the unique FK constraint in the `House` table) or no navigation property at all in `User`. But then you need a navigation reference `User` in entity `House` so that EF would be able to map a relationship at all (at least a navigation property on one side of a relationship is always needed).

Answer (score 0):

Can't rollback to EF4, but was only using it in a similar way a while ago, so don't believe this has changed.

You need to set a Key on the House object and set it to DB generated:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
...

public class House
{
        [Column("house_id")]
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("user_id")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Now i get: A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'House_Id'.

Comment: 1:1 relationships need the dependent to have same primary key.  DatabaseGeneratedOption.None on the dependent primary Key.  Once you Tell EF that you have a 1:1 relationship, it is expecting the same key.  Even though DB first that isnt required. But do you really have a 1:1 relationship ?

Comment: @soadyp is it an optional 1:1, meaning the User account can have 0 or 1 House records.